# Lynx read urls from file and download links

Tags: lynx

1. I have 500 urls on my file.
2. I need to extract all the links which appear on these urls.

How to read file with Lynx and extract links within the file ?

Sample of `file.txt` below, 1 link per row and 500 rows in total

```
https://itunes.apple.com/
https://play.google.com/
```

... and so on

Comment: example of the file ?

Comment: I added sample format on my post. It's just a single ulr in each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an improved script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat file.txt |while read url
do
    lynx -listonly -dump "$url"
done |
awk '/^[ ]*[1-9][0-9]*\./{sub("^ [^.]*.[ ]*","",$0); print;}'| \
sort -u
```

allowing for any type of URL recognized by lynx (including ftp for instance).  The script sorts the result, eliminates duplicates (which lynx will not do by itself).

Further reading:

- [The Lynx User's Guide](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Calling list.txt your list:

```
for i in $(cat list.txt) 
do 
  lynx -accept_all_cookies -dump $i |grep "http" |sed -e "s/^.*http/http/"
done
```

I suggest to redirect the output on some file.

Comment: Why not use `lynx -listonly` and omit the `grep` step?

Comment: good idea, but you need still to clear the 4 line as header